# Same eigenvectors for A and A+rI: why?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I read [Lambiotte 2010, "Multi-scale modularity in complex networks"] that the eigenvectors of an (adjacency) matrix A and the matrix A + rI, with r a scalar and I the identity matrix, are the same. Why is this so? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of a more general result. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$, then there exists $\lambda$ such that $Av = \lambda v$. Now let's look at $A+rI$.

$$(A+rI)v = Av+rIv = \lambda v + rv = (\lambda +r)v.$$

Thus if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, it is an eigenvector of $A+rI$.

Comment: Cool, this is great stuff to be put on my homework assignment for the lin. algebra students. Thanks for posting

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Cameron!

Comment: You're very welcome @Diploria!